# About theme (hugo-academic) in blogdown

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I am trying to install hugo-academic theme in blogdown. Within my site directory I ran R and installed with

```
blogdown::install_theme("gcushen/hugo-academic")
```

After installing I edited the config.toml file as shown below:

```
baseurl = "/"
relativeurls = true
languageCode = "en-us"
title = "A Hugo website"
theme = "hugo-academic"
googleAnalytics = ""
disqusShortname = ""
ignoreFiles = ["\\.Rmd$", "_files$", "_cache$"]
```

After that when I try to serve site with 
    `blogdown::serve_site()`, 
I get the following error:

```
Started building sites ...
ERROR 2017/06/01 20:02:50 Error while rendering "page": template: theme/_default/single.html:10:7: executing "theme/_default/single.html" at <partial "article_met...>: error calling partial: template: theme/partials/article_metadata.html:7:24: executing "theme/partials/article_metadata.html" at <$.Site.Params.date_f...>: invalid value; expected string
Started building sites ...
ERROR 2017/06/01 20:02:50 Error while rendering "page": template: theme/_default/single.html:10:7: executing "theme/_default/single.html" at <partial "article_met...>: error calling partial: template: theme/partials/article_metadata.html:7:24: executing "theme/partials/article_metadata.html" at <$.Site.Params.date_f...>: invalid value; expected string
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error in shell(cmd, mustWork = TRUE, intern = intern) :
  '"C:\Users\Suman\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -b / -D -F -d "public" -t hugo-academic' execution failed with error code 1
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:\Users\Suman\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -b / -D -F -d "public" -t hugo-academic' had status 65535
2: running command '"C:\Users\Suman\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -b / -D -F -d "public" -t hugo-academic' had status 65535
3: running command 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\Suman\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -b / -D -F -d "public" -t hugo-academic' had status 1
```

Any help to solve this?

Note: I am on Windows 10 64 bit OS.

Comment: just a guess, but I think your baseurl should be "." There is more info about this topic here: https://gohugo.io/extras/urls/

Comment: @sinQueso That should not be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the error message, you need to add a `date_format` parameter to your `config.toml` file. Try adding this at the end:

```
[params]
  date_format = "Mon, Jan 2, 2006"
```

Take a look at the [example config file](https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/blob/master/exampleSite/config.toml) for more settings that you can change.

Comment: Yep, I also think that is the problem. @Suman you need to read https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/other-themes.html and I recommended `new_site()` instead of `install_theme()` exactly because of this problem.

Comment: After adding `[params]
  date_format = "Mon, Jan 2, 2006"`, yeah its working. Thanks @Jack Taylor and @Yihui.         blogdown/bookdown/pkgdown are awesome!!